# Generate Excel in Salesforce Visualforce/ Apex

Tags: apex, dynamic-visualforce, excel

Has anyone done Excel file generation in Salesforce with bit complex formatting? If so appreciate any guidance or reference.

I already tried formatting with CSS and having the `contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel"` which doesn't give me the correct formatting always.

[image]
e.g. In the attached image, the table rows/column colspan are dynamic. Background colors work fine with CSS but not colspan or width.

I wanted to try XML option as described [here](https://www.soliantconsulting.com/blog/stylish-spreadsheets-from-a-visualforce-page) but the generated XML file is always having the text `SfdcApp.Visualforce.viewstate.ViewstateSender.sendViewstate('https://cs58.salesforce.com', 'StackingPlanExcelMadhura');` at the end and due to that Excel can't open the file.

Correction for these two options or any other option would be appreciated.

Comment: Found the reason for appended JavaScript tag in the latter part of the question. It's because of previewing from the developer console. When I access the URL directly, Excel opens fine.